# Can a Windows 10 computer use Arduino IDE 1.8.10 sometimes AND use Arduino IDE 2.0.0 the rest of the time?

Tags: code-optimization

Can Windows 10 computer use  Arduino IDE 1.8.10 sometimes, AND use Arduino IDE 2.0.0 the rest of the time?

Comment: why are you asking? ... have you tried to use both versions?

Comment: If it collides, you can add subdirectory "portable" in 1.8.10 and everything will be stored there (boards, sketches, libraries...)

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/is-the-arduino-2-ide-installation-alongside-the-classic-ide-or-a-replacement/698588/2

Comment: I see no reason why not. I have several versions on my Linux machine however each is in its own directory, I would assume you need to do the same with windows.

Comment: i do it the other way around.